# String Split Usage in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to split the e-mails given in an input and put them in a `String`. However, I couldn't do it. Part of the code is below:

```
System.out.println("Please Enter e-mail address(es):");
String inp3 = inputReader.nextLine();
separated = inp3.split(",");

for (int k=0; k<separated.length; k++) {
    System.out.println(separated[i]);
}
```

I've tried many versions of this but I couldn't succeed.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Seems to be right.

Comment: Could you show your input data and what did he print on the console?

Comment: Could you provide `separated` and `inputReader` declaration? And what is your problem actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `for` loop

```
for (int k=0; k<separated.length; k++) 
{
    System.out.println(separated[i]);
}
```

You're iterating over `k` and trying to index using `i`. Change `separated[i]` to `separated[k]` and it should work properly.

If it's not the problem, we'll need some more code and the exact error.

Comment: @user2703902 Mistakes like these can be avoided if you use a for-each loop: `for (String address : separated) System.out.println(address);`